# Self-hosted non-Java search engine for my static websites

Tags: linux, open-source, search-engine, self-hosted

I want to self-host a search engine that indexes my static website(s).

I don’t want to use a CMS (which typically have a search engine built-in) for these sites, and I don’t want to refer my visitors to a third-party search engine service.

It doesn’t have to be a user-friendly search engine (like Google, Bing, etc.), it’s mostly for power users, so a complex search syntax may be required.

#### Requirements

**Formalities:**

- The search engine must be FLOSS.
- It must run on a GNU/Linux server.
- It must not use Java (I know there are several good search engine projects in Java, but, unfortunately, my host doesn’t support it).

**Backend:**

- The search engine must index (X)HTML5. Support for other formats is not needed.
- I don’t want the crawler to find my pages on its own. Instead, I want to provide a list of URLs which should be crawled (ideally supporting one of the [sitemaps.org formats](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html)).
- I don’t want to add metadata about the documents somewhere else than in the documents themselves.

**Frontend:**

- The search engine must not require JavaScript (except for optional features).
- It must not set cookies (unless the user explicitly submits a settings form or similar).

#### My wish list

- **Indexing:** In addition to the full text, it should index as many signals as possible (e.g., in the form of name-value pairs), like meta tags, RDFa/JSON-LD, semantic elements, etc.
- **SERP:** I want to be able to define how the results should look like, depending on the indexed data. Similar to [Google’s Rich Snippets](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/). For example: show an image, a list, a short table, etc.
- **Ranking:** I’d like to be able to tweak the ranking algorithm, e.g., giving each field a certain score/priority.
- **Search operators:** It should, at least, support the Boolean `AND`/`OR`/`NOT` and brackets (e.g., `(laptop OR notebook) (review OR reviews) -netbook`). The more operators, the better (phrase/range/proximity search; field-based search; special characters, case-sensitivity; etc.).

Comment: No Java? No JavaScript? How is it going to run? Am I missing something? Sorry if that sounds rude, it isn't meant to. I am probably just being dumb, as usual :-) I presume you checked SourceForge, etc ...  P.s it ***is*** supposed to run in a browser, isn't it?

Comment: @Mawg: Backend: Instead of Java it can use any other programming language commonly available on Web servers, e.g., PHP, Python, Ruby, or Perl. --- Frontend: There should be no need for JavaScript -- it’s just a plain HTML form for the search field, and a plain HTML list for the results. --- And yes, it’s supposed to be used in the browser -- I’ll integrate it in my website.

Answer (score 0):

What about good old [ht:dig](http://www.htdig.org/)  ?

The last release is from 2004, so I'm not sure how it indexes the new elements introduced by HTML5.

Support for non-html text formats (PDF, DOCX...)  is also suboptimal, but that was not on your list of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend sphinx - see [sphinxsearch.com](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

> Sphinx is an open source full text search server, designed from the
>   ground up with performance, relevance (aka search quality), and
>   integration simplicity in mind. It's written in C++ and works on Linux
>   (RedHat, Ubuntu, etc), Windows, MacOS, Solaris, FreeBSD, and a few
>   other systems.

Sphinx lets you either batch index and search data stored in an SQL database, NoSQL storage, or just files quickly and easily — or index and search data on the fly, working with Sphinx pretty much as with a database server.

I have only good experiences uning it on Linux and Windows.